# volatile keyword : Need explanation for this program behaviour

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

understanding volatile keyword by this program:

```
public class VolatileExample implements Runnable{    
private volatile int vol;
@Override
public void run(){
    vol=5;
    while(vol==5)
    {
        System.out.println("Inside run when vol is 5. Thread is : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            if("t2".equals(Thread.currentThread().getName()))
            {
                System.out.println("Got Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Now Calling Stop To End This Flow");
                stopIt();
            }
    }
}
public void stopIt(){
    vol=10;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
     VolatileExample ve1 = new VolatileExample();
     VolatileExample ve2 = new VolatileExample();

     Thread t1 = new Thread(ve1);
     Thread t2 = new Thread(ve1); //t1 and t2 operate on same instance of VolatileExample class  

     t1.setName("t1");
     t2.setName("t2");

     t1.start();
     t2.start();
 }
}
```

Output:

```
Inside run when vol is 5. Thread is : t1
Inside run when vol is 5. Thread is : t1
Inside run when vol is 5. Thread is : t2
Inside run when vol is 5. Thread is : t1
Got Thread : t2 Now Calling Stop To End This Flow
Inside run when vol is 5. Thread is : t1
```

All writes to vol variable will be written to main memory immediately and should be "visible" to other threads immediately.
Why t1 thread still executes after stopIt() is called? Cant it see that vol value is now 10 and not 5?

Comment: Why do you have `ve2`? Are you trying to confuse us or yourself?

Comment: **Confession**: I got confused!!!

Comment: i was checking program behaviour earlier using ve2, but for this  example, i use ve1 only

Answer (score 3):

There is no evidence of `t1` running after `stopIt()` is invoked.

It can be possible that things happen in this order

```
     t1                     t2
                         System.out.println("calling stopIt()");
while(vol==5)
System.out.println("Inside run")
                         enter stopIt()
                         vol = 10
```

which give you the result you observed. (There are other possibilities of ordering that give you this result.)

Comment: Or `stopIt()` runs between `while` and `println`.

Comment: @shmosel exactly (and that's what I meant by "other possibilities of ordering"  :)  )

Comment: understood, so it all boils down to scheduling of threads and we "cannot" predict the output, is it?

Comment: i tried to print something from stopIt() method after vol=10 i.e. "stopIt called" and i see sometimes "inside run t1" appears even after "stopit called" is printed. The output is different on different runs

Comment: @JyotsanaNandwani check shmosel's comment.  And it is completely normal to see different output on different runs.